# Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT in android Oreo

Tags: android, encryption, aes, android-8.0-oreo

Android Oreo version 8 throws bad decrypt error in production. For other android versions code is working fine.
    Algorithm used is "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding".

```
public String decrypt(String _encryptedText, String _key, String _iv)
            throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {
        //Log.d("enetered decryption", "enetered decryption");

        return encryptDecrypt(_encryptedText, _key, EncryptMode.DECRYPT, _iv);
    }


public String decryptionflag(String input, String iv) {
        String output = "";
        try {
            // CryptLib _crypt = new CryptLib();

            String plainText = input;

            CryptLib _crypt = new CryptLib();

            output = _crypt.decrypt(plainText, key, iv); // decrypt
            //Log.d("decrypted flag is", "" + output);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e){
            Log.e("", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            Log.e("", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (BadPaddingException e){
            Log.e("", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e){
            Log.e("", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            Log.e("", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e){
            Log.e("", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return output;

    }
```

Keys used for encryption and decryption are same. And this code is working for UAT (android oreo version) but giving error for production.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting a similar error in specific devices.